# programmatically turn off playstore ,youtube etc in android

Tags: android

Our company issues Android devices to staff. These devices need to be used only for the purpose of calls, SMSes and GPS navigation. All other activities need to be locked down.

These devices need to be locked to allow only certain features to work, for example:

Waze,Google Maps,Phone,SMS

It needs to lock out a majority of Android features like:

Camera,Hot spot (wi-fi sharing),Play Store,Installation of any unapproved apps,YouTube,Streaming,Data intensive activities,Performance intensive activities

Is it possible to turn them off programmetically in android

Comment: You want to application will work like Applock ?

Comment: Yes Brother . I want my created app will lock all the apps needed . But the employee should not unlock the apps.

Comment: for that you have to make service and please check the code in answer it will help you

Answer (score 2):

You have to enter below code in Android Application Service with the PACKAGE NAMES which you want to block

```
ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
                ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
                activityOnTop=ar.topActivity.getClassName();

                Log.e("activityOnTop", "activityOnTop - "+activityOnTop);

                if(activityOnTop.contains("PACKAGE NAME")){
                    Intent lockIntent = new Intent(this, Restrict.class);
                    lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(lockIntent);
                }
```

This code detect from end application package

In manifest file please give permission as below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

Hope this will help you.

Let me know if you want more help from my side.

Comment: How can  I get activityOnTop variable . What is Restrict class will do ? I should start another activity . I just want when my app will install in my phone all the apps will locked.

Comment: @HasanMasud Just override the back button of that activity to do nothing. User will left with no choice, but press home button. Hence, he will not be able to open the app.

Comment: @Vatsal Can you add "How to get the uninstall intent of an applicaton?", so that the user may not be able to uninstall app locker?

Comment: @berserk Can you give me some code to lock all the apps I mentioned. Code above does not working for me .

Comment: @HasanMasud I checked the above mentioned code and it works fine.